# How to get picture's hex code of every pixel and save as String

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, hex

I am trying to make a RPG game in Java and i have run into a problem when it comes to building the level. It is not getting the hexidecimal code correct. Here is the loop and switch statement that is in question:

```
public void loadLevel(BufferedImage levelImage){
    tiles = new int[levelImage.getWidth()][levelImage.getHeight()];
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            Color c = new Color(levelImage.getRGB(x, y));
            String h = String.format("&02x%02x%02x", c.getRed(),c.getGreen(),c.getBlue());

            switch(h){
            case "00ff00"://GRASS Tile - 1
                tiles[x][y] = 1;
                System.out.println("Found Grass");
                break;
            case "808080"://Stone -2
                tiles[x][y] = 2;
                System.out.println("Found STONE");
                break;
            case "894627"://Dirt -3
                tiles[x][y] = 3;
                break;
            case "404040"://Rock -4
                tiles[x][y] = 4;
                break;
            case "00b700"://Tree -5
                tiles[x][y] = 5;
                break;
            case"000000"://Wall -6
                tiles[x][y] = 6;
                break;
            default:
                tiles[x][y] = 1;
                System.out.println("Did not find anything");
                System.out.println(h);
                break;

            }
```

right now, the string is being set as some variation of `&02x0000` Any ideas/revisions would be very helpful!

Comment: So, why are you using `&` instead of `%` in your format string for the first hex number? Use `%02x%02x%02x` instead of `&02x%02x%02x`.

Comment: wow... I don't know how I missed that. Thank you very much for pointing that out.

Comment: Not really related to the problem (which you have now solved :-) ), but a tip for easier code and better performance: Don't convert to String, just use `int h = levelImage.getRGB(x, y) & 0x00FFFFFF` to mask out the RGB value, and `swicth (h) {  case 0x00ff00:` etc., to switch on the hex values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed `&02x%02x%02x` to `%02x%02x%02x`. Fixed thanks to Jesper